# How to print or export just a part of page

Tags: php, pdf, yii, fpdf, print-style

I'm trying to print/export a part of a page in Yii. 
What's the best way: create a print style sheet or export to pdf.
How to do?
The part of my page that I want to print/export is called:

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by exporting it?

For example, when exporting to JSON or XML, I have "blank" template, where I render a view with XML or JSON format.

For what will be the export?

Comment: Export to pdf or print it, just some images

Comment: I guess you should try this extension: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdf/